# Bluetooth not working properly once restarted via hardware switch

Tags: bluetooth

I usually switch off my bluetooth to conserve the charge while working.

But when I want to use bluetooth again and I switch on the bluetooth back on its not showing available devices like my phone and I am unable to connect my phone to the system by bluetooth.

This can be changed only by restarting the computer. Can any one suggest a corrective measure please? I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please try using the "soft-switch" from the Bluetooth icon on the top panel instead of the hardware switch.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of restarting the computer you can try:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

It's not a permanent fix but it's faster than restarting.  I've never used bluetooth much, but I've found that occasionally if I'm using wifi and do something funky it locks up and I need to restart the network-manager service to get it to recognize the currently available networks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.the solution is working. But as u said I hope to get some permanent fix here.