# Ubuntu doesn't detect my Bluetooth receiver, how to fix it?

Tags: bluetooth

> ### Read first
>
> This is a Canonical question that will be signpost to solve Bluetooth issues. Please, whenever any of this answers does not fix your issue, **provide the same information as this question in another question and add a link to this one**. You should also provide what were the results/changes of each of the solutions.

For about two days now, my bluetooth has not been functional. The bluetooth icon is not present on the top panel. The bluetooth window is completely frozen as can be seen in this picture:

[image: Bluetooth Window]

The output for `bluetoothd -d -n` is:

```
bluetoothd[3390]: Bluetooth daemon 4.98
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() discovto=0
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() pairto=0
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() pageto=8192
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() auto_to=60
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() name=%h-%d
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() class=0x000100
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() discov_interval=30
bluetoothd[3390]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID'
```

The output for `start bluetooth` is:

> start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.343" (uid=1000 pid=19042 comm="start bluetooth ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

My Ubuntu version is 12.04. Any idea as to how this can be sorted?

**EDIT**

Patebin link containing the contents of /var/log/dmesg: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6090733/)

**EDIT #2**

`hcitool dev`:

```
Devices:
    hci0    74:E5:43:36:65:21
```

`cat /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf`:
[paste bin link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6097851/)

`ps aux| grep bluetooth`:

```
root      1065  0.0  0.0   4740  2028 ?        Ss   15:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
dorsatum  2392  0.0  0.2 142772 10956 ?        Sl   15:33   0:00 bluetooth-applet
root     20960  0.0  0.2  76268 10780 ?        Sl   22:08   0:00 bluetooth-applet
dorsatum 21203  0.0  0.0   4388   832 pts/0    S+   22:13   0:00 grep --color=auto bluetooth
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try loading the btusb module before starting the daemon:

```
sudo modprobe btusb
```

To make it happen on reboots put this into `/etc/modules`:

```
btusb
```

The above fixed my case, which was: `sudo service bluetooth start` did not start the daemon and `dmesg` showed

```
[   72.468338] init: bluetooth main process (4028) terminated with status 1
[   72.468401] init: bluetooth respawning too fast, stopped
```

because `/usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n -d` failed with

```
bluetoothd[4054]: opening L2CAP socket: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo service bluetooth restart`

I had similar outputs and found an answer in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179260/bluetooth-not-working-properly-once-restarted-via-hardware-switch). Everything is back to normal for me now.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the bluetooth service, despite the restart is not working, the screen for the service is frozen as it was before and there is no bluetooth icon on the top panel. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the dmesg output: It shows that your bluetooth is initialized and detected.
Are you using laptop with, some special keys for BLUETOOTH: eg: fn+f3 ??

 If anything like that is present,

```
 make sure it is ON.
```

Sometimes this may be the case.

Comment: my laptop DOES have the `fn+f3` combo for WiFi and bluetooth, and it is switched on, but somehow that doesn't change my bluetooth's erratic behavior.

Comment: my Laptop has the same combo feature.... How to you know tht it is switched ON. Is there any indicator,which displays that??

Comment: yep, there's this orange led which signals that the bluetooth service is switched on.

Comment: that orange LED is for both wifi and bluetooth i guess ...!!! See it has happened to me.

Comment: indeed, it's for both the services!

Comment: your issue has been solved right ...??
than it doesn't matter now .... :)

Comment: i hope so! i'll give it just a little bit longer before i confirm, but, with uninterrupted bluetooth for this long, i think it's safe to say that the solution worked

Comment: see, i think, you've used win OS before,and the way to open wifi and bluetooth was using fn+f3 keys....
Try the same sequence for starting for bluetooth service as you used to do for winOS.....
(sometimes may be your bluetooth or wireless may toggle b/w ON/OFF). 
I know it sound's weird, but it did work for me.....

Answer (score 0):

I was running unbuntu in an Oracle VM VirtualBox, and after 30 minutes of trying to figure out why the dongle wasn't showing up, I went to "Devices" under the VM VirtualBox parent menu selected "USB" and then my specific Dongle in my case it was "Cambridge Silicon Radio, Lg Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) [8891]". After that my Bluetooth dongle showed BT devices in my unbuntu VM