# Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000 lag Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, mouse

I have had Ubuntu 12.04 for about a month, and also since then I'm having issues  with my mouse (Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000). After about 30 min -1 hour the cursor starts to lag which is very annoying. The batteries are full, and other usb devices do not display any issues. Are there any drivers I should have installed (I only plugged in the receiver)?

Edit:

The mouse is communicating with a 2,4Ghz Mcirosoft Wireless Transceiver v7.0.

Comment: Unplugging and plugging the receiver helps? Check this question and provide the same outputs http://askubuntu.com/q/321750/169736

Comment: Yes I already have unplugged and plugged the receiver. As far as I know it is not a bluetooth receiver (Microsoft Transreceiver v.7.0).