# Bluetooth not detecting any devices

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, realtek

When Trying to connect to any device through the Device Search it always ends up empty, even when I have my phone, tablet and Bose SoundLink Mini bluetooth turned on at the same time.

[image]

I've tried to find my laptop through my phone, and my phone doesn't even find my laptop. (Visibility is on)

---

I found this: 
[Ubuntu doesn't detect my Bluetooth receiver, how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321750/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-my-bluetooth-receiver-how-to-fix-it)

So here are my outputs of everything:

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ bluetoothd -d -n
bluetoothd[3805]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DiscoverableTimeout' in group 'General'
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() pairto=0
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() pageto=8192
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() auto_to=60
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() name=%h-%d
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() class=0x000100
bluetoothd[3805]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID' in group 'General'
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.88" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
bluetoothd[3805]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ start bluetooth
start: Unknown job: bluetooth
```

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ cat /var/log/dmesg
(Nothing has been logged yet.)
```

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    38:B1:DB:C6:D9:4A
```

cat /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11815776/

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ ps aux| grep bluetooth
jeggy     1566  0.0  0.0 265436  6284 ?        Ssl  15:16   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service
jeggy     2715  0.1  1.1 1027824 96216 ?       Sl   15:23   0:01 unity-control-center bluetooth
root      3402  0.0  0.0  19564  3840 ?        Ss   15:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n
jeggy     3957  0.0  0.0  15164  2476 pts/7    S+   15:41   0:00 grep --color=auto bluetooth
```

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ lspci | grep Net; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0249 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: added 'lspci | grep Net; lsusb; gmesg | grep -i blue'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  install a bluetooth driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8723au-bt-dkms rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

But if you previously installed Realtek wireless drivers from another source, you need to uninstall them first.

Comment: @Pilot6 I had the exact same problem. and solution worked charmingly. But, I can only send fies but not receive any files......... Please help me

Comment: You can search about receiving files in Ubuntu or ask a new question. I do not use BT for that. But I saw solutions.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you, I always had this problem after every installation, so I had added this post to my favourite list and was using the exact solution. But recently I Installed Ubuntu **15.10** , Now when I try to install these it gives this error : **E: Unable to locate package rtl8723au-bt-dkms** , It would be really great if you would add what to do for ubuntu 15 to this answer. Please do not forget to ping me when you are finished ;-P

Comment: That package is not needed for 15.10.

Comment: Does that only work for Realtek? What about `Bus 001 Device 011: ID 413c:8140 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 360 Bluetooth`?