# Bluetooth in Toshiba Satellite C845

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 15.10, toshiba-satellite

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 with Linux 4.2.0-22-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:57:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I cannot enable the Bluetooth device built-in my laptop Toshiba Satellite C845. It has a Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver. There is a device hci0 which I get timeout after command:

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
Inquiry failed: Connection timed out
```

However, I get a MAC address:

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    44:6D:57:05:6A:81
```

I have this output from command:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluet
[    1.590914] usb 3-1.3: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
[    8.168356] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[   10.178847] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   10.178864] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.178868] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.178871] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.178876] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   10.498021] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=0e3d lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=a5b1
[   10.498026] Bluetooth: rtl: assuming no firmware upload needed.
[   17.512991] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.512994] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.512998] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.514692] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c56 tx timeout
[   27.481207] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   27.481216] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   27.481223] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 4118.722944] usb 3-1.3: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
[ 4119.317636] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[ 4119.317646] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[ 4128.043128] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 4235.120749] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 4365.282581] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[ 5014.738593] usb 3-1.3: Product: RT Bluetooth Radio
[ 5015.335446] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=1200
[ 5015.335455] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723a_fw.bin
[ 5023.586749] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 5281.283140] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[ 5294.988048] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9177.900062] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[10898.765848] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c20 tx timeout
[10920.331256] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8801d0bda180 failed to resubmit (113)
[10920.331629] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8801d0bda0c0 failed to resubmit (113)
```

I understand there is a physical device which doesn't get a driver to operate. When I see the output of `lsusb`, then I get:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0930:021d Toshiba Corp.
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          224 Wireless
  bDeviceSubClass         1 Radio Frequency
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0930 Toshiba Corp.
  idProduct          0x021d 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 RT Bluetooth Radio
  iSerial                 3 00e04c000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
```

...
What is missing that I cannot load a driver/module to get enabled this bluetooth device? Is not Toshiba an Ubuntu-friendly manufacturer?

Any ideas, please?

Comment: I'm not happy with the Tumbleweed  achievment that I earned with this question... I really want to find out how to solve it, and so I'm asking for the experts around if they can help me.

Comment: did you solve this issue? If not, I can offer a 500 rep bounty as I need a solution too. If yes, please tell me the solution.

Comment: No, I haven't. Maybe you can open the bounty to everyone else. And I'd love to see the solution.

Comment: Have you tried running a more recent version of Ubuntu? 16.04 or 16.10? There is a chance their more recent kernels support your hardware better. You do not have to install a new version to try it: simply run Ubuntu from a bootable USB key (choose to "try it" and no "install it") and see if Bluetooth works.

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/644073/bluetooth-not-detecting-any-devices) ?

Comment: @George, yes, I have, and was no useful in my case. Thanks.

Comment: @AdrienBeau, yes. In fact, I recently upgraded to 16.04 and the problem remains, or worst:

Comment: @AdrienBeau:

`$ hciconfig -a
hci0: Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
BD Address: 44:6D:57:05:6A:81  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
DOWN 
RX bytes:1848 acl:0 sco:0 events:159 errors:0
TX bytes:25679 acl:0 sco:0 commands:179 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xfb 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT

$ hcitool dev
Devices:  `

This is a 'case for the spider' (a Mexican saying, ;D). I'll keep on waiting for the wizard.

Comment: @AdrienBeau The problem is not with the newer/older OS. The support has been there for long time, it simply works for some OS, and simply doesn't for some. Issue is somewhere in the messy stuff distros do with the kernel/user space stuff. There has to be a solution for this though. Have a look at  this https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/187

Comment: @AdrienBeau, I reported my issue as well, in the same thread you pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: In manjaro, I found this to be issue with runtime power management. Uninstalling the `tlp` package and rebooting fixed the issue. See https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bluetooth-adapter-cannot-be-turned-on-realtek-rtl8723be/10130/29?u=aditya

Answer (score 3):

Similar problems were reported last year here ([kernel 4.1.1: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2286433)) on Ubuntu forums.

Summary of steps to solve it there (**which you probably shouldn't use!**):

```
sudo dpkg -i  linux-firmware_1.145_all.deb
sudo updatedb
rfkill list all; hciconfig -a
```

Updated steps for your Ubuntu 15.10 on the other hand would be:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux_firmware
rfkill list all; hciconfig -a
```

This is based on instructions for 15.10 found here (https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/wily/linux-firmware)

Additional information that may prove helpful can be found here ([Bluetooth not detecting any devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644073/bluetooth-not-detecting-any-devices)) where Pilot6 wrote an answer for an `rtl8723au-bt` driver.

As far as Toshiba's suitability for Linux... historically it has been very good however recently I've read comments some new machines are `Windows only`. In this case however it's more a reflection of RealTek / Broadcom hardware installed inside which Dell's could also have. Either manufacturer could also have Intel hardware WiFi / Bluetooth as well though.

FTR I have a Dell Laptop with Intel inside and haven't had any real bluetooth problems to date (fingers crossed). Hopefully your problems get solved soon!

Comment: I upgraded recently to 16.04, hoping for a solution already set in kernel, but I still have no luck. Thanks, anyway.

My driver is rtl8723a, BTW, and I suppose there are minor but crucial differences with rtl8723au because your suggestion didn't work on 16.04.

Comment: I confirm that installing an up to date linux-firmware is required, along the drivers. For ubuntu 14.04 I installed this: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/linux-firmware
ALSO: I'm running kernel 4.4.0-131

Answer (score 1):

A local AskUbuntu user, Pilot6, provided a PPA ([`ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi`](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi)) containing the required drivers to ensure that the RTL8723 chipset works with your machine.

Essentially, you need to add this PPA to your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi && sudo apt update
```

Next, install the appropriate DKMS modules and drivers to your system:

```
sudo apt install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware rtl8723au-bt-dkms
```

These two commands (combined) will install the required drivers to your system and kernel. Additionally, this will work after any kernel update, due to the nature of DKMS.

Furthermore, you are also installing `linux-firmware`, which allows for some (better) firmware support for similarly quirky devices.

---

If you would rather compile from source, you can see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/607368/208574), which also includes (further) PPA information. Alternatively, if you want DKMS support, [check here](https://askubuntu.com/a/397841/208574).

Comment: Thanks, @kaz-wolfe. Since I changed the version to 16.04, I'll report later (after holidays, ;D ).

Comment: This is required along installing an up to date linux-firmware, for ubuntu 14.04 I installed this: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/linux-firmware

Answer (score 0):

Try this with in terminal :

> sudo apt-get install bluez

More steps are explained here :

http://quehow.com/how-to-enable-and-configure-bluetooth-in-ubuntu/3851.html

So as explained there above this link next steps would be :

> sudo /etc/inet.d/networking restart

and

> sudo /etc/inet.d/bluetooth start

Cheers.

Comment: I already have bluez installed, but still cannot connect. I follwed the tutorial you suggest. Thanks.