# Ubuntu 16.04 Bluetooth not working and finding devices

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

My Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi is not getting connected to my Bluetooth speaker. Even when I try searching for the new device it is not showing anything though the speaker gets connected to my smartphone. My smartphone also doesn't show my laptop's Bluetooth though the visibility is on.

[image]

I have checked blockage, it says no.

There is a similar problem for Ubuntu 14.04 but the solution doesn't work for me 16.04.
[Bluetooth not detecting any devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644073/bluetooth-not-detecting-any-devices)

This is the error I get:  E: Unable to locate package rtl8723au-bt-dkms

I tested for this:

> `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

The output was:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

With `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`, the output was

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE 

PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
DeviceName: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 Combo Adapter
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b50d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also on restarting the bluetooth, it shuts off but does not start.

It's Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

is `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You may check now @Pilot6

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux HP 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

This bluetooth device is not supported by the 4.4 kernel.

Upgrade it to 4.10 by running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Reboot with the new kernel. The BT adapter should work unless there is no firmware.

**Update:** Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` doesn't have `xenial-updates` for some reason.

You can create a default `sources.list`. Delete `/etc/apt/sources.list` by running

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and enable all repos.

Then you'll be able to install `linux-generic-hwe-16.04`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66554/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-ubuntu-16-04-bluetooth-not-working-and-finding-de).

Comment: I updated the kernel. It didnot solve the problem. Rather, I'm getting this error. https://askubuntu.com/questions/898449/kernel-panic-and-unable-to-boot-ubuntu-16-04-after-updating

Comment: After this, my WiFi is also not getting properly connected.

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. It is unclear why you can't install `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` and why you have the 4.8 kernel now.

Comment: Updating the Kernel is a common problem as it has been asked in another question. Moreover, in the previous as well as the present kernel, sudo apt get install bluetooth is not working.

Comment: The problem seems to be version-dependent, so three-year-old references are unlikely to work.  That was my experience. Updating some modules led to progress: instead of a more severe message -- I don't remember exactly what it was  -- I now get the message "device not available" which suggests that at least the software knows it exists.